# Get the count of open tabs in Chrome using auto hotkey

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, autohotkey

I have an AHK script which includes a command to close the current tab in Chrome, but I only want it to close the tab if other tabs are open, otherwise it will close Chrome completely which I can't have.

I haven't found anything useful searching the web.

What I want is something like: if(open tabs > 1) then close tab.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'd probably want to look into Chrome.ahk [AHK Forums](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=42890) and [GitHub](https://github.com/G33kDude/Chrome.ahk).

Comment: You could write a function that copies the current tab title, sends Ctrl+tab to switch tabs (if any), and copies the new tab title. If they are the same, then there is (probably) only one tab, and you return that info. You'll need to Ctrl+shift+tab to undo your side effect.